# YOLOV8 test MAP score

Tags: dictionary, testing, detection, yolo, val

**I can calculate the map score of the validation set using yolo version 8. but is there any way to calculate the MAP of the test score?**

The code for calculating the map of the validation set is given below:

```
!yolo task=detect mode=val model=runs/detect/train/weights/best.pt data=data.yaml
```

What modification is needed to get the test map score?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `split=test` argument as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.ultralytics.com/modes/val/#arguments).